# wxWidgets: How to capture the default configuration values into the nonexisting app.config?

Tags: wxwidgets

**Summary:** Single `App.config` file for everyone using the `App.exe`, `wxFileConfig` that should register default values, the `App.config` should be created with the default values if it does not exist, local vs. global config file.

---

My simple application uses a global configuration file in the same directory where the application is located, with the same name as the executable has, and with the `.config` extension. The configuration file should be created for the user if it does not exist yet. The user is expected to modify the file via editor to replace the default values. So far, I have the following code:

```
// The configuration file name has has the executable name 
// but with the ".config" extension.
//
wxFileName configFileName(wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath());
configFileName.SetExt("config");

// The config object uses the above file name, and captures the defaults.
//
wxFileConfig * pConfig = new wxFileConfig(wxEmptyString,
                                          wxEmptyString,
                                          wxEmptyString, 
                                          configFileName.GetFullPath(),
                                          wxCONFIG_USE_GLOBAL_FILE);
pConfig->SetRecordDefaults();    // to capture the defaults
wxFileConfig::Set(pConfig);      // to be globally accessible

// One of the configuration values is the file name for the exported
// values (the app.exe functionality, unrelated to the config file name).
// It uses a subdirectory with the name built out of the exe path, its name
// without the extension, with the "_OUTPUT" appended.
// For example, "some/path/App.exe" should produce "some/path/App_OUTPUT".
// The file name is again constructed from the bare app name with 
// the ".txt" extension.
//
wxFileName outfname(configFileName.GetPath());            // same as the exe path
outfname.AppendDir(configFileName.GetName() + "_OUTPUT"); // the subdir
outfname.SetName(configFileName.GetName());               // same name as app has
outfname.SetExt("txt");                                   // with the .txt extension
outfname.Normalize();  // actually, my real path contains also ".."    

// The above constructed filename is the default for the "output" key.
// I expect to be recorded into the pConfig because of the above
// pConfig->SetRecordDefaults();   Is my expectation correct?
//
m_output_filename = pConfig->Read("output", outfname.GetFullPath());
```

Now... How to physically write the configuration file if it does not exist yet? I was thinking about something like:

```
if (! configFileName.Exists())
{
    pConfig->??? What should be called?
}
```

Is there any better way to decide whether the file should be written? Say, the `pConfig` was modified by the default values. Is there any way to write back the dirty content?

I have found `Flush()` but it contains the following code at the beginning:

```
if ( !IsDirty() || !m_fnLocalFile.GetFullPath() )
    return true;
```

... and my config file was passed as a global one (see the `wxFileConfig` creation above). No local config file was set. Should I pass the config file as the local one even though it will be a single one for everybody?

**Update:** I tried to change the config file to the local one like this:

```
wxFileConfig * pConfig = new wxFileConfig(wxEmptyString,
                                          wxEmptyString,
                                          configFileName.GetFullPath(),
                                          wxEmptyString,
                                          wxCONFIG_USE_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Then the `Flush()` causes creation of the config file. It is even called automatically probably from the destructor. *But the config file must be the local one.* It does not work for the `wxCONFIG_USE_GLOBAL_FILE` as shown earlier in the question. Can you confirm that? Is it the expected behaviour?

Thanks for your time and experience,

Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wxConfig` absolutely never writes to the global config source (file or registry hive or whatever) by design. To understand why, consider that it simply may not have permissions to do it -- and, in fact, usually won't.

In particular, under Unix the global config file (something like `/etc/myapp.conf`) is supposed to be installed when your program is and edited by the system administrator, not created by the user running the program.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The application that I am writing just now is the tiny one for a bit internal purpose. The reason why I wanted it store the config file was that I am lazy to create it by hand. Probably the better way to generate the default would be to launch the application with some command line option (say -g as doxygen does). Thanks!